# Exception in PortForwarder when adding swagger support to org.glassfish.jersey.server

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish, swagger

I am trying to add swagger support to javax rest apis and ended up having the following exception. Any insights will be helpful.

```
Exception in thread "PortForwarder" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.inclusiveBetween(JJJ)V
    at com.offbynull.portmapper.mappers.upnpigd.externalmessages.ServiceDiscoveryUpnpIgdRequest$ProbeDeviceType.<init>(ServiceDiscoveryUpnpIgdRequest.java:128)
    at com.offbynull.portmapper.mappers.upnpigd.externalmessages.ServiceDiscoveryUpnpIgdRequest$ProbeDeviceType.<clinit>(ServiceDiscoveryUpnpIgdRequest.java:104)
    at com.offbynull.portmapper.mappers.upnpigd.UpnpIgdPortMapper.identify(UpnpIgdPortMapper.java:202)
    at com.offbynull.portmapper.PortMapperFactory.discover(PortMapperFactory.java:58)
    at com.swirlds.p2p.portforwarding.portmapper.PortMapperPortForwarder.execute(PortMapperPortForwarder.java:60)
    at com.swirlds.p2p.portforwarding.portmapper.PortMapperPortForwarder.run(PortMapperPortForwarder.java:172)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code to initialise the server

```
public static void initREST(int port, String[] packages) {
        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://0.0.0.0").port(port).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig()
                .register(new CORSFilter())
                .register(JacksonFeature.class);

        configureSwagger(config);

        for (String pkg : packages) {
            config.packages(pkg);
        }

        System.out.println("Attempting to start Grizzly on " + baseUri);
        GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Code to configure swagger:

```
    private static void configureSwagger(ResourceConfig resourceConfig) {
    resourceConfig.register(ApiListingResource.class);
    resourceConfig.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
    BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
    config.setVersion("v1");
    config.setBasePath("/");
    config.setResourcePackage("ipos.hashgraph.rest");
    config.setPrettyPrint(true);
    config.setScan(true);
}
```

Maven Dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: The error indicates that you have multiple versions of `commons-lang3` on your classpath. Please update the question with your full `pom.xml`.

Comment: I added the below to my pom.xml to avoid conflicts with the other libraries I was using. Still getting the same error  <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: This is the wrong dependency. You need `commons-lang3`.